# Indexing particular fields in Zumo EntityData

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server EntityData, I have a class that looks like

```
public abstract class BaseItem : EntityData
{
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

How do I ensure that the Owner and Text are indexed?

**Update.** I think I can add         [Index(IsClustered = false)]

Answer (score 0):

Use standard Entity Framework semantics.

```
public class BaseItem : EntityData
{
   [Required]
   [Index]
   public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

For more information, see http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx